# Enviar comillas dobles y sencillas dentro de una variable

Tags: php

necesito poner en una variable contenido que lleva comillas dobles, comillas sencillas, /, ... varios caracteres, hay forma de poner todo el codigo dentro de una sola variable? no se hay algo asi *$variable* **<<<** ""''/\ **>>>>**; osea que se pueda poner algun caracter diferenten en el inicio y que cierre con ese en el final donde pueda incluir todos los caracteres que necesito. Osea convertir todo el codigo en un solo string. Gracias.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tu necesitas usar Heredoc, el cual puede ignorar todo carácter raro sacando las variables y las funciones, de acuerdo a lo que interprete de lo que pides, puedes añadirle html si quieres,  ejemplo:

```
 $str = <<<EOF
    "hi world!", 'bye world!';
EOF;

    echo $str;
```

Imprime:

```
"hi world!", 'bye world!';
```

[Documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Comment: Para que lea absolutamente todos los caracteres sin problema hay que agregarle comillas sencillas, quedando de  esta manera
`$str = <<<'EOF' "hi world!", 'bye world!'; EOF;`
Se las he agregado al primer EOF, ya que sin ellas me daba error cuando ponia lo siguente:
`$variable=$assoc["total"];`
no me aceptaba los [ ], pero con las comillas ya me los acepto y todo que funcionando.

Answer (score 10):

Puedes usar comillas simples o comillas dobles para realizar una cadena:

```
$hola = 'hola';
$hola = "hola";
```

Y en ambos casos si imprimes la variable te aparecerá la palabra `hola`.

El problema está cuando intentas usar comillas simples o dobles dentro de este tipo de cadenas. Para ello, tendrás que usar la barra invertida `\` justo antes del tipo de comilla igual que el tipo de comillas que hayas usado para abrir y cerrar la variable.

Ejemplos:

```
$cadena = "esto' es una \" prueba '\r";
$cadena2 = 'esto" es una \' prueba "';
echo $cadena; //Devolverá --> esto' es una " prueba '
echo $cadena2; //Devolverá --> esto" es una ' prueba "
```

También tienes que tener en cuenta que cuando utilices comillas simples para abrir y cerrar un String el String va a ser considerado tal y como es, es decir, si por ejemplo tu pones `\r` dentro de la variable `cadena2` del ejemplo, no te va a realizar un salto de línea si no que te va a imprimir `\r` dentro del String.

Por otro lado, con las comillas dobles el contenido del String va a ser evaluado. Tal y como se muestra en el ejemplo que he añadido antes, `\r` realiza un salto de línea.

Lo único que evalúan las comillas simples es si utilizas una barra invertida para "escapar" una comilla simple o una barra invertida (`\'` o `\\`).

Answer (score 0):

cuando hago esto me ignora mis comillas doble

```
$idgestion = $_REQUEST["id_gestion"];
$idmateria = $_REQUEST["id_materia"];

$iddia = $_REQUEST["id_dia"];
$idhorario = $_REQUEST["id_horario"];
$idsemestre = $_REQUEST["id_semestre"];
$idcarrera = $_REQUEST["id_carrera"];
$nuevo1 =  "\" $idsemestre \"";
$nuevo2 = "\"$idcarrera\"";
```