# Cambio de alert por sweet alert

Tags: php, javascript, sweetalert, sweetalert2

```
      if($resultado_pendientes>=1){

        echo "alert(\"Usted posee 1 solicitud cerrada parcialmente por el departamento de sistemas, valide y cierrela antes de crear otra nueva.\");
              document.location=(\"./listTicketUnrevised.php?active=0\");";
      }

    ?>
```

buenas, necesito ayuda con este codigo que tengo , el cual me genera una alerta corriente y quiero cambiarla por el sweet alert.

el problema es que siempre me da errores .
quiero usar el warning de esa libreria mas no se como implementarlo...

duda 1
no entiendo por que se usan los \dentro del alert pero estoy viendo que sin eso no se imprime el mensaje de alerta.
duda 2 
al cambiar lo que esta dentro de las comillas del echo me sale un error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='
intente meter el document location en el eco pero aun así no funciona.

Comment: Y ¿Cuales son los errores que obtienes y como lo estas implementando?, edita tu pregunta y agrega el código que usas y los errores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eso si lo habia hecho, lo que no habia hecho era separar el php del javascript

```
<script>
        <?php


          if($resultado_pendientes>=1){
//aqui ira el sweet alert y aqui cerre el php , cosa habia hecho despues del sweet alert 
?>
        swal({
  title: 'Tiene 1 ticket pendiente por cerrar',
  html: 'Cierrelos para poder crear uno nuevo ',
  type: 'warning',
  confirmButtonText: 'Got it!'
}).then(function () {
  window.location.href = "tickets-sin-revisar-1";
}, function (dismiss) {
  // dismiss can be 'cancel', 'overlay',
  // 'close', and 'timer'
  if (dismiss === 'cancel') {
    window.location.href = "tickets-sin-revisar-1";
  }
});

          <?php    
//aqui lo vuelvo a abrir para cerrar el if continuando con mi js   
//este codigo lo copie de la web de aca , yo le hice la modificacion  al darme //cuenta y funciono , me redirije a la pagina que quiero , ya le agrego el //tiempo de redireccionamiento usando la version 2del sweet alert.
//posteo el codigo para que la gente se ayude si tiene este problema
// saludos 
          }
        ?>
    });

  </script>
```

Comment: gracias por la edicion @ruben , asi ahora se ve mucho mas facil.
tengo que aprender a hacer eso aqui (y)

Answer (score 3):

A la respuesta de cómo implementar un `Sweetalert2`, sólo tienes que añadir las librerías necesarias, `jQuery` y las propias de `sweetalert2` y luego modificar la sintaxis del `alert`.

Aquí te dejo una muestra funcionando. y [aquí](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) su web con más información sobre los parámetros configurables

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/6.11.0/sweetalert2.css"/>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/6.11.0/sweetalert2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function alerta(){
 swal({
   title: "¡ERROR!",
   text: "Esto es un mensaje de error",
   type: "error",
 });
}
     alerta();                   
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Si lo que quieres es mostrar el alert desde `php`esto te puede servir, fíjato cómo combino las comillas dobles y las simples:

```
<?php echo "<script> swal({
   title: '¡ERROR!',
   text: 'Esto es un mensaje de error',
   type: 'error',
 });</script>";
?>
```

En [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/34013/7478) encontrarás más información sobre lo de las comillas.

Comment: gracias bro, fijate abajo como lo solucione