# Como puedo usar un Sweet Alert en un echo?¡

Tags: php, sweetalert2, echo

Mi siguiente codigo es para registrar usuarios, todo va bien... Si las contraseñas coinciden se registra el usuario en mi BD, pero si no solamente manda a la pagina sin hacer el registro y aqui es donde quiero que mande un echo con una alaerta de sweetalert que diga que las contraseñas no coinciden.

```
include '../ConexionABaseCondominio.php';
$dataTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$paterno = $_POST['paterno'];
$materno = $_POST['materno'];
$correo = $_POST['correo'];
$correo2 = $_POST['correo2'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$contra = $_POST['contra'];
$confirmar_contra = $_POST['confirmar_contra'];
$id_cargo = $_POST['id_cargo'];

$completo = $nombre . " " . $paterno . " " . $materno;
$correoF = $correo . "@" . $correo2;

if ($_POST["contra"] === $_POST["confirmar_contra"]) {
    $consulta = $conexion->query("INSERT into usuarios (id,nombre, paterno, materno, completo, correo, telefono, usuario, 
contra, id_cargo) VALUES (null, '$nombre','$paterno','$materno','$completo','$correoF','$telefono','$usuario',
'$contra','$id_cargo')");
    echo "<script> window.location= '../xUsuarios.php' </script>";
} else {
//Aqui quiero colocar la alerta
    header('Location: ../xUsuarios.php');
}
```

Y el sweet Alert que quiero colocar es el siguiente

```
Swal.fire({
  icon: 'error',
  title: 'Oops...',
  text: 'Las constraseñas no coinciden, Intentalo de nuevo.',
}) ``
```

Comment: Investigastes como hacerlo? Porque puse tu pregunta en google y la primera opcion me salio esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/144774/cambio-de-alert-por-sweet-alert

Comment: No me funciona :/

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Cambio de alert por sweet alert](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/144774/cambio-de-alert-por-sweet-alert)

Comment: Lo he colocado en mi codigo y no funciona...

Comment: `} else {
    echo "<script> swal({
        title: '¡ERROR!',
        text: 'Esto es un mensaje de error',
        type: 'error',
      });</script>";
    echo "<script> window.location= '../xUsuarios.php' </script>";
}
`
Simplemente no me manda la alerta...

Comment: Dónde tienes tu formulario? Si usas Ajax para hacer el submit sería fácil manejarlo. Simplemente envías una respuesta y en el success del ajax creas la alerta.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que yo hago es llamar a la librería SweetAlert2 cuando la voy a usar, osea donde se reciben las respuestas de mi código y cuando las voy a mostrar con un echo las hago de la siguiente manera:

```
echo '<script>
        Swal.fire({
         icon: "error",
         title: "Oops...",
         text: "¡La contraseña no coincide!",
         showConfirmButton: true,
         confirmButtonText: "Cerrar"
         }).then(function(result){
            if(result.value){                   
             window.location = "../xUsuarios.php";
            }
         });
        </script>';
```

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAAAAAAAAAAAAS!!!! Tu solucion fue la que me ayudo, agaredeszo tu tiempo bro :)

Comment: Que bueno hermano de nada que Dios te bendiga, si puedes pon la respuesta como correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que hice fue mandar llamar la libreria de sweetalert2 con un include donde tengo todos mis scripts.

```
<header>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"></script>
</header>
```

Despues ese archivo llamado scripts.php lo mande a llamar a mi codigo.

```
<?php
include '../ConexionABaseCondominio.php';
include '../scripts.php';
$dataTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$paterno = $_POST['paterno'];
$materno = $_POST['materno'];
$correo = $_POST['correo'];
$correo2 = $_POST['correo2'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$contra = $_POST['contra'];
$confirmar_contra = $_POST['confirmar_contra'];
$id_cargo = $_POST['id_cargo'];

$completo = $nombre . " " . $paterno . " " . $materno;
$correoF = $correo . "@" . $correo2;

if ($_POST["contra"] === $_POST["confirmar_contra"]) {
    $consulta = $conexion->query("INSERT into usuarios (id,nombre, paterno, materno, completo, correo, telefono, 
    usuario, contra, id_cargo) VALUES (null, '$nombre','$paterno','$materno','$completo','$correoF','$telefono',
    '$usuario','$contra','$id_cargo')");
    echo "<script> window.location= '../xUsuarios.php' </script>";
} else {
    echo '<script>
        Swal.fire({
         icon: "error",
         title: "Oops...",
         text: "¡La contraseña no coincide!",
         showConfirmButton: true,
         confirmButtonText: "Cerrar"
         }).then(function(result){
            if(result.value){                   
             window.location = "../xUsuarios.php";
            }
         });
        </script>';
}
```

Y listo mi resultado final, fue lo que yo queria.